# Truecrypt run from USB: Can run w/o admin mode? Secure? Temp files?

Tags: windows, usb, encryption, truecrypt

I am trying to create a secure USB drive using Truecrypt, but I am confused on a couple of issues, so I have some questions:

1)  Can Truecrypt be run from the USB drive (in portable mode) *without* Administrator privileges?  I'm getting conflicting answers in my research:  someone here said that it works fine in portable mode from a USB, but the user guide says that you must have administrator privileges to run it in this fashion.  Which is correct?

2)  Isn't it possible for someone--say, an administrator--to capture the passkey you input when using Truecrypt in this fashion (from USB on another computer)?  Someone mentioned using a virtual keyboard (I know Windows has one)...but am I correct in thinking that won't help?

3)  Another encryption program, SafeHouse Explorer, has a feature that I love: it securely deletes any temporary files created by Windows programs when using encrypted files (like MS Word does).  Truecrypt does not do this, correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Can Truecrypt be run from the USB drive (in portable mode) without Administrator privileges?

On Windows, Truecrypt uses a kernel driver to make the encrypted partition or encrypted container file look and act like a normal Windows volume.  (It's Any kernel driver on Windows requires Administrator privileges to install.  No way around that.

> Isn't it possible for someone--say, an administrator--to capture the passkey you input when using Truecrypt in this fashion (from USB on another computer)?

If a keylogger is running, it will capture your keystrokes, regardless of why you are entering those keystrokes, regardless of whether or not Truecrypt is running.  If you enter your Truecrypt password via keyboard while such a keylogger is running, it will capture your password.  You can change your password and the original password will be useless to retrieve your data, as the password protects a key and is not directly used to decrypt data.

> Truecrypt does not do this, correct?

Truecrypt allows access to encrypted partitions or container files by inserting itself, using a driver, between the low-level routines that physically read/write data to devices, and the OS that issues read/write requests.  It also has a bootloader that allows booting a fully-encrypted disk.  It does nothing more.  It does not know about or care about the specific files or filesystem on the partition or container file it has encrypted.

Comment: You might want to make it clear that Truecrypt would be using a Windows kernel driver, only because in this context, the user is using Windows.  It took even me a minute to understand, the reason, for what you said.

Comment: Hopefully my edit is clearer ... :)